# How do I change facial expressions on a V3 or V4 model imported into Blender using the DAZ Bridge plugin?

Tags: export, import, pose-mode

I have exported several V3 and V4 model from Daz Studio into Blender using the Blender\Daz Bridge software supplied with Daz V4.15.

I can import the base mech and the rigging, and everything functions correctly for the body and hands, but I cannot locate any controls that would allow me to adjust the facial expressions once I'm in blender. There are no drag handles for the face in Pose mode, and I cannot find any menu options or sliders in the Blender GUI.

Now that I'm in blender how do I change the expressions?

My aim is to be able to re-use content I already own from Daz Studio rather than having to purchase or sculpt new models.

This is a question about what to do with the models once they are in Blender, not about the models, daz studio, or the bridge software.

Comment: According to the Daz Bridge manual, you can't, using the armature that comes with the import.  It looks like you have to replace their rig with one of your own in order to do facial animation.  Maybe ask on their forums to see if there's a rigify option?

Comment: In the latest version you can use the armature as well. The models arrive fully rigged for movement, but not for morphs.

Comment: This is a blender question, not a daz one